# Probability calculation: Bulbs are produced in $3$ locations..

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Bulbs are produced in $3$ different locations $I,II,III$. Every hour,
>   $I$ produces $300$ bulbs, $II$ produces $200$ bulbs and $III$ produces
>   $500$ bulbs. $B$ is the event that represents a defective bulb that
>   has been picked out. It's also known that of each $1000$ produced
>   bulbs, $15$ bulbs of $I$, $6$ of $II$ and $45$ of $III$ are defective.
>   Determine the probability $P(A_i \cap B)$ for the events $A_i \cap B$

So I thought it would be helpful to firstly calculate the probability to get a bulb from $I, II, III$

In total we have $1000$ bulbs produced every hour, $300$ of them in $I$, $200$ in $II$, $500$ in $III$. Thus we have probabilities

$P(A_1)= \frac{300}{1000}= 30$%, $\text{ }$ $P(A_2)= \frac{200}{1000}= 20$%, $\text{ }$ $P(A_3)= \frac{500}{1000}= 50$%

The probability  we pick a defective bulb from these $1000$ is $\frac{15+6+45}{100}= \frac{33}{500}= 6.6$%

Now we are supposed to calculate $P(A_i \cap B)$. What does that mean? I think that notation is equal to $P(A_i)-P(B)$. Thus we have $P(A_1)-P(B) = 0.3 - 0.066= 0.234 = 23.4$% and we apply the same for $i=2, i=3$

Is it right like that? If not I hope you can show me how it's done correctly?

Comment: You don't define the $A_i$. What events are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\cap$  means intersection.

$A_i \cap B$ is the event that both $A_i$ happens and $B$ happens.

In general $P(A_i \cap B ) \neq P(A_i) - P(B)$

If $A_i$ means a bulb is produced in location $I$.

$Pr(A_1 \cap B)$ is the probability that a bulb was produced in location $I$ and it is defective.

Comment: Let me try an example with your definition for $i=1$. We have probability of $30$% to get a bulb from location $I$. Now that it's also a detective bulb, the probability is $\frac{15}{300}$. So we just need to do $0.3 \cdot \frac{15}{300}$ to calculate $P(A_1 \cap B)$ ?

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Comment: Great, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

First it must be cleared what is the meaning of "..of each $1000$ produced bulbs, $15$ bulbs of *I* .." . Normally speaking that should mean

- a) ".. out of $1000$ bulbs produced by **each plant**, ...", (i.e. we give the defective rate of each single plant) and not
- b)".. out of $1000$ bulbs **totally produced**.

Supposing a) is the correct interpretation,
then every hour *I* produces $300$ bulbs, $15/1000$ of which are defective, so $=4.5$ defective/h, *II* will produce $200 \cdot 6/1000=1.2 d/h$ and *III* will produce $500 \cdot 45/1000=22.5 d/h$.
Thus totally there are $D=28.2 d/h$ and the probabilities required will clearly be $4.5/D,\; 1.2/D,\; 22.5/D$.

In the interpretation b) instead
$D$ would be $66 d/h$, and the probabilities $15/D,\; 6/D,\; 45/D$.

Comment: Haha this is confusing, I cannot tell. The task itself is unclear for me as well, I'm not even entirely sure what $i$ is. I just assumed it represents the locations, first, second and third. I should ask my teacher before handing it in :o Thank you for your answer too! :D

Comment: @cnmesr: you can always present the answer under both interpretations

Comment: It sounds reasonable but our proofreaders are a bunch of... They will most likely take the wrong interpretation and evaluate it :s